# how to write proper like statements for beginning and end cases at hibernate 5.4.2

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

I am using hibernate version 5.4.2. I user "%" in the beginning and "%" in the end of like predicates. Do you think is there any other word for "like statements" rather than using "%" at the beginning and end of the like case ?

You can see the sample code below that I use for like statement.

```
 predicate = criteriaBuilder.and(predicate, criteriaBuilder.like(criteriaBuilder.lower(root.get(PROJECT_NAME)), "%" + StringUtils.lowerCase("Project CQ") + "%"));
```

Comment: looks you can use stars too: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19226-01/820-7627/gjixa/index.html

Comment: You mean for wildcard matching? `LIKE` is the only standard operator that is widely available with minimal difference between databases. Some databases support the `SIMILAR TO` operator or even POSIX regular expressions, but neither of those is available through CriteriaBuilder, nor JPQL. They can only be used in native queries.